# NumberFormatException when trying to convert JTextField to Integer

Tags: java, user-interface, object, constructor, jtextfield

I've tried many things and I still can't seem to fix this error no matter what so I'm going to ask my own question.

I keep believing that the error is at the ActionEvent where I try to convert the JTextfield into an int but it might be something else? Thanks :)

I have an object in another class that I need to send the data to in order to construct it. This is the object

```
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public Account(int startAmount, int balance, int credit, String Name, String    Address)  {       
    openingBalance = startAmount;
    currentBalance = balance;
    creditLimit = credit;
    accountName = Name;
    accountAddress = Address;

    numOfAccounts++;
}
```

And now the rest of my code,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AccountGUI extends JFrame{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

String Name;
String Address;
int balance;
int credit;
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

public AccountGUI(){

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.ipadx = 20;
    gbc.ipady = 20;

    JLabel enterYourName = new JLabel("Name:");
    JTextField textBoxToEnterName = new JTextField(20);
    JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
    addHelper(enterYourName,0,0);
    addHelper(textBoxToEnterName,1,0);

    JLabel enterYourAddress = new JLabel("Address:");
    JTextField textBoxToEnterAddress = new JTextField(20);
    addHelper(enterYourAddress,0,1);
    addHelper(textBoxToEnterAddress,1,1);

    JLabel enterYourBalance = new JLabel("Current Balance:");
    JTextField textBoxToEnterBalance = new JTextField(0);
    addHelper(enterYourBalance, 0,2);
    addHelper(textBoxToEnterBalance, 1,2);

    JLabel enterYourCreditLimit = new JLabel("Credit Limit:");
    JTextField textBoxToEnterCreditLimit = new JTextField(20);
    addHelper(enterYourCreditLimit, 0, 3);
    addHelper(textBoxToEnterCreditLimit, 1,3);

    JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Name = enterYourName.getText();
            Address = enterYourAddress.getText();
            try {
                int balance = Integer.parseInt(enterYourBalance.getText().trim());
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception : "+ex);
            }
            try {
                int credit = Integer.parseInt(enterYourCreditLimit.getText().trim());
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception : "+ex);
            }
            Account record = new Account(0, balance, credit, Name, Address);
        }
    });
    addHelper(submit,0,4);

    setTitle("AccountGUI");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);


}

private void addHelper(JComponent item, int x, int y){
    gbc.gridx= x;
    gbc.gridy= y;
    add(item,gbc);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AccountGUI promptForName = new AccountGUI();
    promptForName.setVisible(true); 
}


}
```

The error message I get is

```
Exception : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Current Balance:" 
Exception : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Credit Limit:"
```

Comment: What do `enterYourBalance.getText().trim()` and `enterYourCreditLimit.getText().trim()` return?

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: I think you have to convert text from `JTextField ` and not from `JLabel ` to `int`.

Comment: Swing must always be run the the EDT. Your code initialises the GUI on the `main` thread. This is fundamentally incorrect.

Comment: Kishore have the correct answer

Comment: learn to understand the error message because most of the time it will tell you exactly whats wrong with your code

Comment: Try to get value from JTextField, Currently you getting from JLabel

Comment: Consider using a `JSpinner` or `JFormattedTextField`, they will validate themselves and save you from having these type of issues. See [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) and [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JLabel enterYourBalance = new JLabel("Current Balance:");
JTextField textBoxToEnterBalance = new JTextField(0);
...
int balance = Integer.parseInt(enterYourBalance.getText().trim());`
```

`enterYourBalance.getText().trim()` will return `"Current Balance:"` and parsing it to `int` fails. Change to 
`textBoxToEnterBalance.getText().trim()` to get the text from the text field.

Answer (score 0):

You ask to parse from `enterYourBalance` but your `JTextField` is `textBoxToEnterBalance`. 
In your code replace the corresponding line by:

```
int balance = Integer.parseInt(textBoxToEnterBalance.getText().trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int balance = Integer.parseInt(enterYourBalance.getText().trim());
```

enterYourBalance is JLabel object

Edit like this

```
    int balance = Integer.parseInt(textBoxToEnterBalance .getText().trim());
```

Try to get value from JTextField Not from JLabel